# Calling stored procedure with table type input parameter in sql server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jdbc

I want to call a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 from Java code. The stored procedure takes user defined table type as parameter(basically array) 
Please can you give me Java syntax to call the stored procedure and pass the array as input parameter

Comment: Please post example on how you are calling this in T-SQL first.

Comment: declare @list countarray
insert @list(n) values ('Resistivity'),('Porosity'),('Mud')
exec arrayex @list//call to procedure arrayex

Comment: Refer this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/04/03/how-would-you-use-table-valued-parameters-tvp.aspx and this http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html for some insights.

Comment: thanks bimalesh for the links but could get answers to my question

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see your stored procedure clearly but here is the passing Array by example for any JDBC.

```
  try {
     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://yourdb.yourco.com:12345;databaseName=MyDataBase;", "user", "password");
     CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("{call arrayex(?)}");
     Array arr = con.createArrayOf("varchar", new String[]{"ABC","DEF"});
     st.setArray(1, arr);
     st.execute();
     st.close();
     con.close();
  } catch (Exception exp) {
     System.out.println("Error " + exp.getMessage());
     exp.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: i am getting below error java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported.                                                           stored procedure takes tablevalued parameter as arrays is not supported in pl/sql